# Какими инструментами можно выполнить статический или динамический анализ кода на C# бесплатно?

Tags: c#, поиск-программ, статический-анализ, динамический-анализ

Какие есть бесплатные для коммерческого использования инструменты для статического или динамического анализа кода на языке программирования C#? Нашел только SonarQube Community.

Comment: Предполагаю, что качественный анализ бесплатным не будет. В качестве платного но с массой вариантов лицензии предлагаю посмотреть в эту сторону: https://pvs-studio.com/en/

Comment: Пожалуйста давайте вопросам нормальные названия )

Comment: что такое "динамический" анализ кода?

Comment: @Grundy можете ввести в поисковике - достаточно популярная штука, судя по всему

Comment: А чем не устраивает анализатор встроенный в Visual Studio?

Comment: Как вариант. Но не все платформы его поддерживают и не во всех редакциях он есть.

Comment: [Overview of .NET source code analysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/overview?tabs=net-8). Следует включить AnalysisMode/AnalysisLevel. По умолчанию они не заданы на максимум. В самом конце упомянуты Third-party analyzers.

Comment: @Ingvar, самая дешёвая лицензия на этот продукт стоит 1230000 рублей за год.

Comment: @FAQ, если вы работаете в конторе и получаете деньги - то пусть контора и покупает. если проект от студентов или оперсорс - есть вариант легального использования не покупая - https://pvs-studio.ru/ru/order/for-students/ .... и еще тут: https://pvs-studio.ru/ru/blog/posts/0614/